# Tabela editável em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap-3, modal

Tenho uma tabela com uma lista de empresas. Quero a partir de um click na linha da tabela carregar um modal com as informações desta empresa. Alguma sugestão de como fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faço isso manipulando o DOM, através de atributos customizados, tipo data-id="id-do-teu-registro"

```
<tr data-id='2'>
  ....
</tr>
```

No Javascript, crio uma função, na qual ira fazer uma requisição via ajax para uma função php que me retornara os dados da empresa em json, no momento que eu clicar na linha

```
$('tabela>tr').on('click',function(){
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       $.ajax({
          url:url-de-requisicao.php
          type:'post',
          dataType:'json',
          data:{id:id},
          success:function(data){
          $('input#nome').val(data.empresa)
          $('input#endereco').val(data.empresa)
          $('#modal-empresa').modal('open');

};
});
});
```

Neste exemplo estou recebendo 'data', que são os objetos vindo da url requisitada, e populo os campos do formulário do modal.

```
$.modal()
```

É uma biblioteca do Bootstrap.

Espero ter dado mais claridade a esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está um exemplo simples [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pmn1ems/3/): Aqui a relação é feita entre o valor do atributo `data-show` e o nome do input que temo no form

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
  var dados = $(this).parent().children(); // selecionamos todos os irmãos ('td')
  dados.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).data('show'));
      // relacionaos o valor de dada-show de cada um com o nome dos inputs do form e definimos o valor destes como sendo o texto dentro das ('td')
      $('#myModal input[name="' +$(this).data('show')+ '"]').val($(this).text());
  });
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>


<tr>
    <td data-show="nome">
      nome1
    </td>
    <td data-show="telefone">
      telefone1
    </td>
    <td data-show="email">
      email1
    </td>
    <td data-show="endereco">
      endereço1
    </td>
    <td class="edit"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td data-show="nome">
      nome2
    </td>
    <td data-show="telefone">
      telefone2
    </td>
    <td data-show="email">
      email2
    </td>
    <td data-show="endereco">
      endereço2
    </td>
    <td class="edit"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-show="nome">
      nome3
    </td>
    <td data-show="telefone">
      telefone3
    </td>
    <td data-show="email">
      email3
    </td>
    <td data-show="endereco">
      endereço3
    </td>
    <td class="edit"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  </table>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST">
               nome
               <input name="nome" type="text">
               <br>
               telefone
               <input name="telefone" type="text">
               <br>
               email
               <input name="email" type="text">
               <br>
               endereço 
               <input name="endereco" type="text">
               <br>
               <input type="submit">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```