# Problemas ao passar ID para janela MODAL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página com uma tabela que lista as informações necessárias e nela vários botões como deletar, alterar, visualizar. O problema é que quando clico em visualizar (chama o MODAL) ele deveria listar uma informação detalhada referente aquele registro selecionado, porém tenho um problema quanto a passagem do id para fazer a consulta e apresenta-lo na tela.

Segue código:

```
<?php include ("cabecalho.php");?>
<?php include ("conexao.php");?>
<?php include ("funcoesBD.php");?>


<?php
//verificaUsuario();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $produtos = buscaProdutoNome($conexao, $nome);

}else{
  $produtos = listaProdutos($conexao);
}


?>

<form action="consulta-produto.php" method="post">
  <td>
    <label  for="nome">Nome:</label>  
    <input  type="text" name="nome">
  </td>

  <button type= "submit" name="submit" style="border-radius: 3px; width: 80px; height: 30px;"><b>Pesquisar</b></button>
</form>


<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="table table-hover">

  <thead >
    <tr>
      <th style="display: fixed;">Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Cor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <?php
    foreach($produtos as $produto) :
  ?>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!--<td><?= $produto['id'] ?></td>-->
      <td><?= $produto['nome'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $produto['preco'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $produto['cor'] ?></td>

      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="form-altera-produto.php?id=<?=$produto['id']?>">Alterar</a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$produto['id']?>">
        <button value="<?=$produto['id']?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Visualizar</button>
      </td>

      <td>
        <form action="deleta-produto.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$produto['id']?>">
          <button class="btn btn-danger confirmation-callback" onclick="return (window.confirm('Certeza que deseja remover?'));">Remover</button>
        </form>
      </td>

    </tr>  
  </tbody>



  <?php
    endforeach;
  ?>

</table>



<!-- MODAL -->

<?php 
  $id = $produto['id'];
  echo $id;
  $produtos = buscaProduto($conexao, $id);
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Informaçoes de Produto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Nome: <?= $produtos['nome'] ?><br> 
        Preço: <?= $produtos['preco'] ?><br>
        Cor: <?= $produtos['cor'] ?><br>
        Peso: <?= $produtos['peso'] ?><br>
        Tamanho: <?= $produtos['tamanho'] ?><br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--FIM MODAL -->

<?php $totalPagina = paginacao($conexao);

echo "<ul class= pagination pagination-large>
        <li><a href = consulta-produto.php >Primeira Pagina</a></li>
      </ul>";
echo "<ul class= pagination pagination-sm>
        <li><a>...</a></li>
      </ul>";

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){

    echo "<ul class= pagination pagination-large>
            <li><a href = \"?pagina=$i\">$i</a></li>
          </ul>";
}

echo "<ul class= pagination pagination-large>
        <li><a>...</a></li>
      </ul>";


echo "<ul class= pagination pagination-large>
        <li><a href = \"?pagina=$totalPagina\">Ultima Pagina</a></li>
      </ul>";
?>

</div>

<?php include ("rodape.php");?>

<?php 



?>
```

Já tentei passar via POST, colocar o valor no botão como esta ali, porem ele sempre me trás o último ID, no caso o último de cada página pois são listados 5 registros por página.

Comment: Se der uma pesquisada no site, vai achar muito conteúdo sobre o [seu problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vari%C3%A1vel+modal)

Comment: Sim, porem sem exito com as soluções apresentadas.

Comment: Sua linha que está com o id está comentada, é proposital? Qual o erro que acontece, ou o que acontece ?

Comment: A linha com o id comentada é proposital sim.. na verdade como viu ali eu fiz uma paginação, então eu listo de 5 em 5 registros, logo quando clico em visualizar ele chama a div correspondente ao modal portanto ele sempre passa o ultimo ID do registro, sempre o ultimo e não o que clico.

Comment: E como está sua query?

Comment: query seleciona a consulta do produto pelo id que deveria ser recebido pelo modal...$query = "select * from produto where id = '{$id}'";

Comment: Eu acho que já respondi a uma pergunta parecida... Veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130803/passar-id-de-um-dado-de-uma-tabela-para-a-modal-resolvido ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130169/tabela-edit%c3%a1vel-em-php

Comment: é exatamente o segundo link o que gostaria de fazer, vou tentar adaptar. obrigado

Comment: @MHPA Já fez teste modal sem php?

Comment: Nao.. na verdade nao entendi bem, poderia explicar?? obrigado

Comment: @Miguel deu certo consegui com o segundo link das opções que me passou porem ele mostra os dados em um input.. como fazer para apenas mostrar sem o input?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ooexfj26/

Answer (score -1):

No arquivo principal:

```
<button onclick="$('#modal-container').load('modal.php?id=1', function(){$('#modal').modal('show');})">Abrir modal com id = 1</button>
<button onclick="$('#modal-container').load('modal.php?id=2', function(){$('#modal').modal('show');})">Abrir modal com id = 2</button>
<div id="modal-container"></div>
```

No arquivo modal.php

```
<?php // $registro = SELECT no banco baseado em $_GET['id'] ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Título do Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Conteúdo do Modal com os dados de $registro -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acho que você deveria montar o MODAL separadamente em outro arquivo "modal.php". Assim, quando clicasse no botão correspondente, ele chamaria uma funcao do tipo $("#modal-container").load("modal.php?id=X"). No fim do arquivo modal.php deve haver o script $("#modal").modal("show") para que seja exibido.

Comment: Desculpe nao entendi muito bem, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Agora sim entendi.. vou analisar essa solução tambem..Obrigado