# Passando informação para uma Modal

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, bootstrap

Eu tenho essa rotina usando o Razor do C#. Ela faz a listagem da minhas mensagens :

### Código:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                <div class="box-body" style="line-height:15px">
                    <ul class=" products-list products-list">
                        <li class="timeline-item">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img src="/Content/imagens/principais/no-user.png" alt="Product Image" style="height:40px">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <a href="" class="product-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    @if (Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Nome != null && Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Nome.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        @Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Nome;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Email;
                                    }


                                    @if (Model.Mensagens[i].Visualizada == false)
                                    {
                                        <span class="label label-primary pull-right">Não lida</span>
                                    }
                                </a>
                                <span class="product-description">
                                    @Model.Mensagens[i].Conteudo
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Repare no link:

```
<a href="" class="product-title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Eu tenho essa Modal em uma `_PartialModalLayout`  que eu chamo com `@Html.Partial()`.  A ideia do funcionamento é quando eu clicar no `Cliente.Nome` ele abrirá a Modal com algumas informações.

Aqui esta parte da minha Modal (Lembrando que ela esta em um arquivo separado)

```
<div class="box box-info">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4>Cliente</h4>
                            <input type="email" disabled value="@if (@Model.Mensagens[id].Cliente.Nome != null)
                                                                { @Model.Mensagens[id].Cliente.Nome}else{ @Model.Mensagens[id].Cliente.Email}"
                                   class=" form-control" name="emailto" placeholder="Email to:">
                        </div>
                        <h4>Mensagem</h4>
                        <div>
                            <textarea disabled  id="MensagemRecebida" style="min-width: 100%;height:120px;display:block">@Model.Mensagens[id].Conteudo</textarea>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                            <textarea id="EscreverMensagem" style="min-width: 100%;height:150px;margin-top:20px " placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Eu tentei usar o `data-id`, mas não consegui. Como posso abrir a modal passando as informações da mensagem e cliente?

EDIT- Eu estou usando uma script o seguinte script :`  $(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {

            var data_id = '';

            if (typeof $(this).data('id') !== 'undefined') {

                data_id = $(this).data('id');
            }

            $('#myModal').val(data_id);
        })
    });
```

`

Supondo que esse seja o script certo, depois que eu passo esse `data-id` para a modal como eu consigo usar este id na modal ? eu tentei algo tipo, `@Model.Mensagem[id].Conteudo`  mas não reconhece a variavel id.

Comment: Veja se alguma destas ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130803/passar-id-de-um-dado-de-uma-tabela-para-a-modal-resolvido ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130169/tabela-edit%c3%a1vel-em-php

Comment: Hey Como está chamando o modal ?

Comment: vou verificar esse post Miguel , e fiz um Edit paulo_tully,  Obrigado pela atenção .

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar varialvel para modal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80035/passar-varialvel-para-modal)

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração, deem uma olhada , eu estou lendo os post que me mandaram para ver se consigo arrumar.

Comment: William Cézar, tentei editar o seu post para ficar mais claro, veja se capturei o que você queria.

Comment: Sim basicamente é isso Anthony, como eu tenho um for para a listagem das mensagem não sei como passar o índice do cliente para a Modal , para eu recuperar as informações dele lá.

Comment: Fiz um update espeficando mais um pouco a minha duvida, se algum conseguir me ajudar, ate agora não consegui resolver.

Comment: Consegui uma solução e respondi minha pergunta, deem uma olhada na resposta, caso esteja confusa eu tento arrumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma :

A chamada da Modal foi alterada, em vez de `data-target=""` foi colocado `href=""` foi adicionado o alias para a como classe `class="openMyModal product-title"`
por fim foi criado um Json no data id com as atributos que eu queria passar para  a modal :

```
data-id='{"nome": "@Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Nome", "pessoaId": @Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.PessoaId, "mensagemId": @Model.Mensagens[i].MensagemId, "conteudo": "@Model.Mensagens[i].Conteudo", "clienteId"}'
```

a chamada ficou assim:

```
  <a class="openMyModal product-title" data-id='{"nome": "@Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.Nome", "pessoaId": @Model.Mensagens[i].Cliente.PessoaId, "mensagemId": @Model.Mensagens[i].MensagemId, "conteudo": "@Model.Mensagens[i].Conteudo"}' data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
```

Depois eu criei o seguindo javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".openMyModal", function () {
    var data = $(this).data('id');        
    $("#clienteNome").val(data.nome);
    $("#mensagemConteudo").val(data.conteudo);

});
```

O javascript ja serializa o Json, no caso quando eu faço var `data = $(this).data('id');`  a `data` já está recebendo um Json com as informações.

Na Modal nos Elementos em que eu quero que recebas as informações eu adiciono o id `#clienteNome` ou `#mensagemConteudo`

Exemplo:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            <h4>Cliente</h4>
                            <input id="clienteNome" type="text" disabled  class="form-control" name="emailto" placeholder="Email to:">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>Mensagem</h4>
                            <textarea class="textarea" id="mensagemConteudo" disabled style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
```

Assim quando abria a modal ela já carrega as informações na Modal.