# Inserir uma variável para consulta e exibir dados em uma Modal já ativa em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal

Sou novo em PHP e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho um Modal, que carrega automaticamente os dados de uma consulta predefinida e está funcionando!

O que eu preciso implementar: **Digitar uma variável e exibir o resultado nesta mesma Modal**. Isto é possível? Se não, qual a melhor maneira de fazer?

**Abaixo um print da tela atual:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Js

```
$('#item-add').on('click', function(){
     $('body').modalmanager('loading');
     setTimeout(function(){
         $modal.load('?ng=ps/modal-list/', '', function(){
             $modal.modal();
         });
     }, 1000);
 });
```

## Formulário que chama o Modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="item-add">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> {$_L['Add Product OR Service']}
</button>
```

## PHP que carrega o Modal (Onde está minha dúvida)

```
case 'modal-list':

//**Consulta padrão atual**
$d = ORM::for_table('sys_items')->order_by_asc('name')->find_many();

//**Consulta com a váriavel (O que eu gostaria de implementar. Neste caso, deixaria de usar a consulta acima)**
//$name = 'caneta';        
//$d = ORM::for_table('sys_items')->where_like('name','%'.$name.'%')->find_many();  

echo '
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
   <h3>'.$_L['Products n Services'].'</h3>
</div>


//**Aqui está o input para inserir a variável**

<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="'.$_L['Search by Name'].'..."/>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-primary">'.$_L['Search'].'</button>
      </div>
   </div>


   //**Resultado abaixo**

   <table class="table table-striped" id="items_table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th width="10%">#</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$_L['Item Number'].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$_L['NCM'].'</th>
            <th width="40%">'.$_L['Item Name'].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$_L['Price'].'</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
';

foreach($d as $ds){
   $price = number_format($ds['sales_price'],2,$config['dec_point'],$config['thousands_sep']);
   echo '<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="si"></td>
   <td>'.$ds['item_number'].'</td>
   <td>'.$ds['ncm'].'</td> 
   <td>'.$ds['name'].'</td>
   <td class="price">'.$price.'</td>
   </tr>';
}
echo '
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">'.$_L['Close'].'</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary update">'.$_L['Select'].'</button>
</div>';

break;
```

Comment: Talvez alguma destas o ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130803/passar-id-de-um-dado-de-uma-tabela-para-a-modal, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130169/tabela-edit%C3%A1vel-em-php

Comment: Olá Miguel. Obrigado pela atenção. No meu caso o Modal já está inicializado e tabela vazia. A ideia é fazer a consulta com a variável na própria Modal.

Comment: Olá Marcelo, seja bem vindo! Eu não entendi a pergunta propriamente dita > **Digitar uma variável e exibir o resultado nesta mesma Modal**. Como Assim? Você poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: O usuário vai digitar uma palavra chave nessa modal, e vc quer que o resultado apareça sem que seja redirecionado. É isso?

Comment: Ola Andrei. Obrigado pelas boas vindas. 
É isto mesmo. A imagem acima é o modal.
Ao digitar a variável e clicar em [ Procurar ] o resultado seja exibido na table do mesmo Modal.

Comment: Deu certo Marcelo?

Comment: Oi Andrei. Queria muito agradecer sua atenção e dispor do seu tempo e conhecimento para me ajudar. 
Infelizmente ainda não consegui fazer funcionar...rs 
Estruturei do jeitinho que vc mostrou, mas não deu certo. Vou continuar tentando aqui. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: Andrei. Deu certo! Um pequeno ajuste nas urls. 
Poxa, valeu mesmo pela força. Um grande abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver isso, você pode usar o `AJAX` com `jquery`. Mostrarei um exemplo abaixo de como funciona, porém você terá que molda-lo conforme sua necessidade pois não sei como você quer que seja exibido o conteúdo e também não tenho informações do seu banco.

Para usar essa técnica é necessário a biblioteca [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/)

Vamos lá. Abaixo eu criei uma parte do seu modal para servir de exemplo, incluí `ids` e incluí uma `div` que estará com as informações que serão pesquisadas, veja:

```
<div id="info">
    <!-- As informações serão mostradas aqui -->
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <input id="pesquisa" type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
    <button  id="procurar" class="btn btn-primary">Procurar</button>
</div>
```

Quando o usuário digitar a informação no `input` e clicar em `procurar`, ele chamará o seguinte script:

```
// biblioteca jquery
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// script que foi acionado pelo usuário
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#procurar').click(function () { // "#procurar" é o id do botão que o usuário apertou
     var pesquisa = $("#pesquisa"); // "#pesquisa" é o id do input que o usuário digitou
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'pesquisa.php', // esse é o arquivo que fará a pesquisa
         data: { value: pesquisa }, // aqui é lançado a variável da pesquisa
         success: function (result) {
            $('#info').html(result); // aqui ele altera a div que você quer que apareça a informação
         }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Esse script será acionado após o click, irá resgatar a informação do `input`, vai enviar essa informação para o arquivo **pesquisa.php** que fará a pesquisa no banco e irá gerar o conteúdo:

```
<?php 

    // valor enviado pelo usuário através do ajax
    $pesquisa = $_POST['value'];
    // faz a pesquisa no banco a partir do valor que foi enviado
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT ... WHERE pesquisa LIKE '%$pesquisa%' ORDER BY ..."); 

    // Gera a informação que será inserida na div INFO do modal
    echo '<table class="table table-striped" id="items_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>';
    while($_L = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<th width="10%">'.$_L['Item Number'].'</th>';
        echo '<th width="10%">'.$_L['Item Name'].'</th>';
    }

?>
```

Esse conteúdo gerado irá ser mostrado na div info.

Qualquer dúvida deixe nos comentários que responderei assim que puder.